# What happens when you call str() on a unicode string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I'm wondering what happens internally when you call str() on a unicode string.

```
# coding: utf-8
s2 = str(u'hello')
```

Is s2 just the unicode byte representation of the str() arg?

Comment: I don't mean to be too harsh, but... how about you just try it and see?  When you try it, does it look like Unicode bytes?

Comment: I was asking more about the internal representation of unicode and how it translates given different use cases (albeit wrong use cases).
The example was just a trivial one that was only meant to illustrate the use case. I would think that the result of it would be fairly obvious, especially since utf-8 is compatible with ascii.
I don't see what your comments really add, though I could have made the question more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will try to encode it with your default encoding. On my system, that's ASCII, and if there's any non-ASCII characters, it will fail:

```
>>> str(u'あ')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u3042' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Note that this is the same error you'd get if you called `encode('ascii')` on it:

```
>>> u'あ'.encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u3042' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

As you might imagine, `str` working on some arguments and failing on others makes it easy to write code that on first glance *seems* to work, but stops working once you throw some international characters in there. Python 3 avoids this by making the problem blatantly obvious: you can't convert Unicode to a byte string without an explicit encoding:

```
>>> bytes(u'あ')
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

Comment: Oops, I missed the word "internally". +1 :)

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realize str() was affected by your system default encoding. Mine was utf-8 which meant it always worked for me.